# Error in batch script : `missing operands` and incorrect seconds calculations

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, error-handling

edit: getting missing operands errors the formula this script is ment to first convert the video length to seconds and display it in output.md , it does work on most part but for some files it just doesnt shows correct like i have a file which is 17 min and 08 seconds it has to be 1028 but it shows 1020

The error I am getting:

`Invalid number.  Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11), or octal (021). Missing operand.`

I am not getting how to fix it.

This is the code for my batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "output_file=output.txt"

rem Delete the output file if it already exists
if exist "%output_file%" del "%output_file%"

for %%i in (*.mp4 *.avi *.mkv *.mov *.wmv *.flv *.mpeg *.mpg) do (
    set "input_file=%%i"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i "!input_file!" 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration"') do (
        set "duration=%%a"
        set "duration=!duration:*Duration=!"
        set "duration=!duration:~0,12!"
    )

    set "duration=!duration:.=,:!"
    set "duration=!duration:~1,-1!"

    for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=,:." %%a in ("!duration!") do (
        set /a "hours=%%a, minutes=%%b, seconds=%%c, milliseconds=%%d"
        set /a "total_seconds=hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds"
        set "hhmmss=%%a:%%b:%%c"
    )

    echo Filename: "!input_file!" >> "%output_file%"
    echo Duration: !hhmmss! >> "%output_file%"
    echo Total Seconds: !total_seconds! >> "%output_file%"
    echo. >> "%output_file%"
)

echo Output has been written to "%output_file%"

endlocal
```

Comment: Change `(in megabytes)` to `(in megabytes^)`.

Comment: thankyou so much let me try this out

Comment: You also can't nest delayed variables like that (the interpreter thinks you said `!ResolutionDescs:~!`, then the literal string `index`, then `!,1!`), so you're going to have to have an extra `for` loop to put the value of `!index!` in a different variable.

Comment: thankkyou @SomethingDark il keep this mind as well actually i am learning few new things and lost in most of them

Comment: @Compo sir missing operand error please suggest solution


`for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=,:." %%a in ("!duration!") do (
        set /a "hours=%%a, minutes=%%b, seconds=%%c, milliseconds=%%d"
        set /a "total_seconds=hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds"
        set "hhmmss=%%a:%%b:%%c"
    )`

Comment: There is none of that code in your question submission. If you need further assistance you should ideally submit another question, or at the very least, [Edit] this one, to include **all** of your code, and include all of the pertinent information.

Comment: @Compo i am trying to edit earlier too but keep getting

`It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.`

Comment: @Compo thannkyou sir i fully understood now

Comment: What is the output from, ```ffmpeg -i "1.mkv" 2>&1 | find "Duration"```?

Comment: @Compo FIND: Parameter format not correct

Comment: There is a possibility that you have no such file as `1.mkv`. Are you sure that `1.mkv` shouldn't be `%%i` instead? ```for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('ffmpeg -i "%%i 2^>^&1 ^| find "Duration"') do (```.

Comment: @Compo il try that suggestion too when i reach home after office...but i am sure there is a file 1.mkv in the same folder as script

Comment: @Compo sir can u please check this edited msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first mistake is in using ffmpeg to get the duration from the files. I would advise that you use ffprobe instead.

You main problem is well documented and is the fact that you are trying to perform `set /a` arithmetic with numbers which could be identified as octal, (base8), rather than the intended decimal, (base10).

Here's an idea of how I may attempt the task:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Set "output_file=output.txt"

(
    For %%G In (*.mp4 *.avi *.mkv *.mov *.wmv *.flv *.mpeg *.mpg) Do (
        For /F "Delims=" %%H In ('P:\ath\To\ffprobe.exe -i "%%G"
         -show_entries format^=duration -v quiet -of csv^="p=0" 2^>NUL'
        ) Do (
            Set /A ss=%%~nH,hh=ss/3600+100,ss%%=3600,mm=ss/60+100,ss=ss%%60+100
            Echo Filename: "%%G"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            Echo Duration: !hh:~1!:!mm:~1!:!ss:~1!
            EndLocal
            Echo Total Seconds: %%~nH
            Echo(
        )
    )
) 1>"%output_file%"

Echo Output has been written to "%output_file%"

EndLocal
```

Comment: @Campo u nailed it sir thankyou so much, i made a silly mistake

Comment: thanks sir wasnt aware , did it right away

Comment: sir can u please check the new core error , thankyou

Comment: I have undone your latest edit @AdityaYadav. You were describing a completely new and unrelated problem. Please submit it as a new question instead.

Comment: apologies sir , done